# How to not retrieve parent information in JPA

Tags: java, rest, jpa

I have two entities which I'll name `A` and `B`. 
B is mapped to A like so:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=A.class)
private A parent;
```

and A has the other relationship:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=B.class)
private List<B> children;
```

In my clientside, I then have a call which gets all Bs in the database with parent A using a named query:

```
Select b from B b where b.m_parent=:parent
```

The problem is that while this works fine and I get all the elements, the json of every B includes `owner:{//A's info}`.

Is there a way to make so I dont return A's information for every element of B I am querying?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned json, I assume you are serializing the query result. It seems A's data are being fetched (either eagerly / lazily) because your json serializer assumes `parent` contains important data to be serialized.

You need to skip `parent` field when serializing (eg with `@Transient` annotation or other ways depending on your json library)

Comment: but if I do that, then the NamedQuery no longer works because I don't have access to the field parent

Comment: You need to somehow make it transient to the json serializer only, not JPA